# React Js Card Component doesn't support border width and color

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Card component(from MaterialUI framework) for a Web Site built using Reacts , I'm facing a problem when i try to modify the border width , color and shadow of the Card components, it seems like it doesn't work .
This is my Code :

```
       <Card
            style={{
              display: "inline-block",
              margin: "0 2px",
              transform: "scale(0.8)",

                borderWidth: 50, 
                shadowColor: 'red', 
                shadowOffset: { height: 50, width: 20 },
                shadowOpacity: 0.9,
                shadowRadius: 0.9,
            }}
          >
```

Comment: What is a `Card` component? Is it your custom component? If it's from 3rd party library you should look at related docs. Please show `Card` implementation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the card component is from materialUi framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MUI you style with [Hook API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    minWidth: 275,
    border: `2px solid red`,
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  },
});

export default function SimpleCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      ...
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `makeStyles` function and assign a custom class (here `root`) to the `<Card>` component like this

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "inline-block",
    margin: "0 2px",
    transform: "scale(0.8)",
    borderWidth: 50,
    shadowColor: 'red',
    shadowOffset: { height: 50, width: 20 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.9,
    shadowRadius: 0.9,
  },
});

const CardWrapper = ()=>{
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}/>
  )
}
```

Refer this https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#SimpleCard.js

Hope this helps !